# Using a custom member from [Date] dimension within Descendants function

Tags: mdx

1.This works:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[DaysComplete] AS
  Descendants
  (
    Tail([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month]).Item(0) 
   ,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
   ,SELF
  ).Count
```

Returns 16 as expected as 1-16 October are in our cube

2.This doesn't work:

```
MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Month] AS
    Tail([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month]).Item(0) 
MEMBER [Measures].[DaysComplete] AS
  Descendants
  (
    [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Month] 
   ,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
   ,SELF
  ).Count
```

Returns the integer 0

Why does the 2. return 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second approach, you create a **new** member of the `[Date].[Date - Calendar Month]` hierarchy, you do not create a reference to the existing member. This new member - like all calculated members - does not have any descendants.

If you need the original member, not a new one, in your calculation, then you could get around that with a named set containing just this member. The set - even if it itself is a new object - would contain the original member, not a new one.
I would assume that

```
SET [My Month] AS
    Tail([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month]) 
MEMBER [Measures].[DaysComplete] AS
  Descendants
  (
    [My Month].Item(0)
   ,[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
   ,SELF
  ).Count
```

would deliver what you expect.